# AWS EC2 is running but website is showing connection time out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connection-timeout

I am running Bitnami WordPress on AWS server website working since two days but suddenly it stop showing anything and connection timeout is showing. The instance EC2 is running perfectly fine, and I have also seen IP logs, and nothing suspicious has come up.

Comment: Login to the EC2 instance and check if the server is running fine

Comment: its running completely fine

Comment: Is it running behind a load balancer? if so, check the health of its instances

Comment: Nope load balancer is not created

Comment: Can you paste your sample URL

Comment: 24dimension.com

Comment: Try with the EC2 public IP and see if you can reach it

Comment: 52.89.180.9 this public ip

Comment: 52.89.180.9 is giving a 404. To me it indicates that the web server is not running correctly

Comment: but instances is working correctly

Comment: Your instances may be running correctly, but the web server within that may be down

Comment: can you tell how to solve this issuse

Comment: Check to see if the web server is running, if no, start it. If it is running then debug your webserver why it is not serving the requests as you would debug assuming it would be on your local machine instead of the EC2

Comment: I'll try but please be with me till now your comments are very helpful

Comment: Now server is running but nothing is showing up .

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above comments I guess the issue is with the internal web server

Make sure that the web server is running perfectly fine. And I do not mean just checking the EC2 instance state, because it is possible that the EC2 instance is running but the web server is down, causing the issue

Comment: I shifted on new instances and start working from scratch again that's why website is coming up but i don't understand why the server get closed by itself?

Comment: So in future it stop again how I may restart it ?any reference for future knowledge

Comment: Have you configured security groups appropriately?

Comment: can u tell me what appropriately means ?

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with security groups.. you would need to setup some extensive logging to find out what is causing your internal web server to choke up.. because I still feel this issue might be more to do either with your code or the internal web server setup and not with AWS infrastructure

Comment: Yeah I have found that it was due to PHP syntax error .

Comment: So is it all running fine now